# Django Show Subcategories by Category Id

Tags: python, django, categories

I have a problem (I think) with urls and views. So that, I have 3 categories, and each of them has 3 subcategories. I want to open subcategories when clicked on each category.

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    url(r'^category/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.category, name='category'),
]
```

views.py:

```
def category(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    subcategories = SubCategory.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'category.html', {'categories': categories, 'subcategories': subcategories}
```

base.html:

```
{% for category in categories%}
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'category' pk=category.pk %}">{{ category.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image_url = models.CharField(default=0, max_length=2000)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: Can you provide models for Category and SubCategory? Also i don't think you need 2 model to handle subcategories.

Comment: You should add the model to your question.

Comment: @Navid2zp thank you, I did

Answer (score 1):

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    url(r'^get_subcategory/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.get_subcategory, name='get_subcategory'),
]
```

models.py(should like this)

```
class Category():
     name=models.CharField()

class SubCategory():
     name=models.CharField()
     category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

views.py

```
def get_subcategory(request, pk):
        category = Category.objects.get(id=pk)
        subcategories = SubCategory.objects.filter(category=category)
        return render(request, 'category.html', {'categories': categories, 'subcategories': subcategories}
```

html

```
{% for category in categories%}
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'YourAppName:get_subcategory' pk=category.id %}">{{ category.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. but what about urls and showing them in base.html ? how can I do it ?

Comment: it returns error like this "TypeError at /category/1
category() got an unexpected keyword argument 'category_id' " @jackquin

Comment: Please check again my comment. Changed according to your workflow

Comment: I'm so sorry, man, but still returns en error: TypeError at /get_subcategory/1
'Category' object is not iterable